# Excel memory leak when importing and exporting text file data

Tags: vba, excel, memory-leaks

I have a an excel program with multiple `userforms` that is meant for creating text files out of data from a master sheet, as well as importing data into multiple other sheets and for creating charts out of the imported data.

I have been having memory leak problems and just made sure that all objects are set to nothing before `subfunctions` end. This did not seem to help.

It seems like the memory usage stays high after all the functions are done running and they become progressively slower the more often the are run.

I suspect the memory leak may be the result of one of the following:

1. Using `TextToColumn` method when importing data. Not sure if this plugs up memory after the function finishes.

The code looks like this:

```
    Set Temp = Workbooks.Open(FileLocation)                      
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
        Temp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy .Cells                         
        .Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
                                  Space:=True, _
                                  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True       
        .Columns(1).Delete                                         
        Temp.Close SaveChanges:=False                              
    End With
    Set Temp = Nothing
```

2. Creating arrays of data (about 1 x 60) and writing them into text files. Also unsure if this clears after the function ends.

   ```
   DataList = Application.Transpose( _
              Application.Transpose( _
                .Range(.Cells(R, Lines_C_datastart), _
                       .Cells(R, Lines_C_dataend)))) 
   If SheetWriter(ShtName, DataList()) Then SheetCreator = True
   ```
3. Global Variables. I created some short functions to behave like Global Constants, but they vary between two values depending on a particular flag. In these I `Set` the function return value to a value.

I wonder if this causes memory problems, since there is no occasion to `Set` it back to `Nothing`. They look like this, and there are many of them:

```
    Function INPUT_FOLDERNAME() As String
        Select Case SIMTYPE_KEY
            Case T_SIMTYPE_A: INPUT_FOLDERNAME = "input_files_A"
            Case T_SIMTYPE_B: INPUT_FOLDERNAME = "input_files_B"
        End Select
    End Function

Some of them are ListBox object functions that I made just for convenience in working with the names (not having to have the module name included) and I'm thinking these may pose a problem:

    Function LINES_BOX() As MSForms.ListBox     
        Set LINES_BOX = Exporter.LINES_BOX
    End Function

(This way, I just use LINES_BOX anywhere in the project instead of Exporter.LINES_BOX.)

If anyone can see a particular issue that may be contributing to memory leak, or knows what the common causes are, any help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: [Setting objects to nothing is rarely necessary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing.aspx) - the vast majority of instances where objects aren't getting released that I've seen were caused by improper form handling.  What indication do you have that you are leaking memory?

Comment: Basically every time I run the program, I can see the physical memory usage of the exvel instance jump up and stay up. Sometimes up to 350K. The program also slows down and gets sluggish. Tbh, I'm not sure what is a normal amount of memory for the program to use.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. I wrote a little test code in VBA that opened and then closed hundreds of other, small Excel files. Using the Task Manager, I found Excel eating up tons of space.

I was able to fix the problem in Excel 2010 by adding a `doEvents` call after closing each file.